# What are all the integral solutions of $n!=m(m^2-1)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, diophantine-equations, integers

Observe that:

- $3!=2(2^2-1)$
- $4!=3(3^2-1)$
- $5!=5(5^2-1)$
- $6!=9(9^2-1)$

**Question**: What are all the integral solutions of $n!=m(m^2-1)$?
I guess it is just $(n,m) = (3,2),(4,3),(5,5),(6,9)$, but how to prove that there is no other one?

I checked that there is no other one for $n<20$.

---

Let reformulate the problem using [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula):    consider the cubic equation $$x^3+px+q=0,$$
its discriminant is $\Delta = -(4p^3+27p^2)$. Our case corresponds to $(p,q) = (-1,-n!)$, so $\Delta = 4-27(n!)^2 <0$. Thus the cubic has one real root and two non-real complex conjugate roots, and by Cardano's formula, the real root is $$ \left(-\frac q2+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}} \right)^{1/3} +\left(-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}\right)^{1/3} $$
So the problem "reduces" to ask whether there exists an integer $n>6$ such that
$$ \left(\frac{n!}{2} +\sqrt{\frac{(n!)^2}{4} - \frac{1}{27}} \right)^{1/3} +\left(\frac{n!}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{(n!)^2}{4} - \frac{1}{27}} \right)^{1/3}  $$
is also an integer. It is not clear that it helps...

Comment: [On AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1214916p6040036)

Comment: Try using $m(m^2 - 1) = (m-1)m(m+1)$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire but that link does not contain a solution, so what's the purpose of linking to it?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the last three known solutions are related to exceptional isomorphisms of finite groups $2\cdot\mathrm{Alt}_n \simeq \mathrm{SL}(2,m)$ (and the first solution is related to $\mathrm{Sym}_3 \simeq \mathrm{SL}(2,2)$). I wonder if the problem becomes any easier when $m$ is restricted to be a prime power.

Comment: @pregunton: yes this is precisely how I came to this problem.

Comment: If I come up with partial solutions to the more generalized elliptic curve version of your problem that don't have immediate corollaries as partial solutions to your problem, would you like me to include them anyway?

Comment: @MiloMoses: Yes sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Richard Guy's third edition of Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, he writes on p.301 in D25 Equations involving factorial $n$. that

> Simmons notes that $n!=(m-1)m(m+1)$ for $(m,n)=(2,3),(3,4),(5,5),$ and $(9,6)$ and asks if there are other solutions. More generally he asks if there are any other solutions of $n!+x=x^k.$

This Simmons is in reference to:

> Gustavus J. Simmons, A factorial conjecture, *J. Recreational Math.*, 1(1968) 38.

So it would seem that this problem was open in 2004 when Guy wrote the third edition of his book, but I don't know if it has been solved in the last 17 years.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly enough, there might be something even deeper going on. Let us define a family of elliptic curves given by the Weierstrass equations

$$E_n: y^2=x^3-x-n!$$

Your question is asking whether $E_n$ has any integer solutions $(x,0)$, which by the [Nagell-Lutz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem) is equivalent to asking if $E_n$ has any points of 2-torsion. A natural generalization of this conjecture is to ask whether or not the torsion group $E_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial for any $n\neq3,4,5,6$.

Using [Sage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SageMath) one can compute the torsion groups of elliptic curves, and computationally it checks out that $E_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial for any $n\leq10,000$, except for $n=3,4,5,6$ where we have that the only torsion points were the points of 2-torsion.

It turns out, in fact, that this generalized problem is $\mathbf{equivalent}$ to your conjecture. This is true because $x^3-x$ is always a multiple of $3$ (check by hand of by Fermat's Little Theorem) so any non $2$-torsion solution $y^2=x^3-x-n!$ will also be a multiple of $3$. By Nagell Lutz this would imply that the discriminant $\Delta_{E_n/\mathbb{Q}}=-4(27n!^2-4)$ would be a multiple of $3$ which as we can clearly see it is not.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I learnt a lot from this. +1!

Answer (score 2):

Variations of your problem are very well studied. For example, Brocard's problem asks about whether or not there are any solutions $(n,m)$ to $n!=m^2-1$ other than $(4,5)$, $(5,11)$, and $(7,71)$. This conjecture dates back to Erdos.

An interesting generalization is asking how many solutions $n!=P(m)$ has for any integer polynomial. Under the abc conjecture, there are only ever finitely many solutions if $P(m)$ has degree at least $2$.