# Solve this equation: $3^{3x} - 3^x = (3x)!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation:

$$3^{3x} - 3^x = (3x)!$$

We have to solve for $x$ integer. I did try to attempt but to no avail. I can't manipulate any side of this equation. I took common $3^x$ in the LHS of the equation and got a product: $(3^x) (3^{2x}-1)$ but I have no idea what to do in the RHS of the equation (which is a factorial). It looks like the answer is $x=2$ but I want to solve it algebraically.

Any hints/solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for an integer solution? otherwise the expression $(3x)!$ makes no sense (unless you introduce the gamma function).

Comment: @FeedbackLooper Yes, I am looking for an integer solution. This equation equates for x=2. I want to solve it algebraically.

Comment: Actually, I suppose one could a priori only demand that $3x$ be an integer. But then $3^x$ is forced to be an integer, which in turn forces $x$ to be an integer.

Comment: @user123 Added to the post itself for you, next time please include such details in the post itself, not just a comment. Anyway one strategy could be to try to show that right hand side is greater than the left hand side for $x \geq 3$ (induction?).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The main idea is that $n!>a^n$ for $n$ sufficiently large, so there is only a finite number of values to check.

In this problem, a simple mathematical induction shows that $n!>3^n$ for every $n\ge 7$. Therefore, for $x\ge 3$, we have $(3x)! > 3^{3x} > 3^{3x} - 3^x$.

Now, the equality is satisfied for $x=2$ ($3^6-3^2=720=6!$) but not for $0$ ($3^0-3^0=0\neq 0!$) or $1$ ($3^3-3^1=24\neq 3!$)

Comment: (+1) Excellent answer! I particularly like its simplicity, and how you don't need an advanced level of knowledge to understand it.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a way by comparing exponents of $3$ on both sides for $x \geq 3$.

Notice that RHS is divisible by
$$
(3x)(3x-3)(3x-6)\cdots(3)=3^x(x(x-1)\cdots 1)=3^xx!.
$$
Because $x \geq 3$, this means $3 \mid x!$ and in turn $3^{x+1}$ divides RHS. But that means it must divide LHS as well, i.e. $3^{x+1} \mid  3^{3x} - 3^x = 3^x(3^{2x} - 1)$ (the equality you have found). But this means $3 \mid 3^{2x}-1$, impossible.

Answer (score 4):

A factorial can be written as a product of three subsequent integers only in very few cases, in particular:
$$\begin{aligned}1\times 2\times 3&=3!\\2\times 3 \times 4=24&=4!\\4\times 5\times 6=120&=5! \end{aligned}$$ or
$$8\times 9\times 10=720=6! $$
LHS of the given equation is $$3^{3x} - 3^x = (3^x-1)(3^x)(3^x+1),$$ which is a product of subsequent integers where the mid-term is a power of $3.$ Comparing with the listed possibilities, only the last one satisfies. Here $3^x=9$ or $x=2.$

Comment: Nice answer. How do you justify that a product of three consecutive integers is a factorial only in the few cases you mentioned?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4005878/290240) indicates it might be an open problem...

Comment: @Sil thank you for the link, I could not find it (or a similar) yesterday. I find the question challenging and the solutions nice.

Comment: @Taladris My first idea was thinking of the Gamma function. Then I noticed that OP did not accept your excellent solution. Thus I decided to write my solution as simple as possible, maybe for high-school level. I agree there is a gasp :)  One possible generalization of the given problem is to solve in integers $n!=k!m!,$ because the equation can be written as $(3^x+1)!=(3x)!(3^x-2)!$ For this, [see the link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199508/a-set-of-integers-whose-factorial-can-be-written-as-a-product-of-two-factorials), which could complete my answer.